# php if statement in error handling

Tags: php, if-statement, error-handling

For some reason the second half of my error validation is not working unless the first half errors out.  See comments.  Can someone please spot my error?  I don't want to use if/elseif because I want multiple errors to print within the div if they exist.

```
    // Validation errors        
    if ($user && ($user !== pg_fetch_result($result, 0, 'user_name'))) { 
        echo "<div id='custom'><ul><li><font color='#672330'>&#187</font> The username you entered is invalid. 
              <div id='noteii'>Please go back and re-enter your current username or contact your account representative for assistance.</div></li></ul></div>";
        }
    if ($pass && ($pass !== pg_fetch_result($result, 0, 'user_pass'))) { 
        echo "<div id='custom'><ul><li><font color='#672330'>&#187</font> The password you entered is invalid. 
              <div id='noteii'>Please go back and re-enter your current password or contact your account representative for assistance.</div></li></ul></div>";
        }
    // Now, if the all of the above are error free the next lines don't work?!...But, the next lines do work if either of the above show errors?! :|
    // Validate password(s)
    if ((strlen($newpass) < 5) || (strlen($newpass) > 15)) { 
        echo "<div id='custom'><ul><li><font color='#672330'>&#187</font> The new password you entered is invalid (Password must be 5 to 15 characters, CaSe SeNsItIvE).
              <div id='noteii'>Please go back and re-enter your desired password(s) password or contact your account representative for assistance.</div></li></ul></div>";
        }       
    if ($newpass !== $cfmpass) { 
        echo "<div id='custom'><ul><li><font color='#672330'>&#187</font> The passwords you entered do not match. 
              <div id='noteii'>Please go back and re-enter your desired password(s) or contact your account representative for assistance.</div></li></ul></div>";          
        }
    //
```

EDIT: this code is actually wrapped up in a parent ELSEIF statement, not sure if that makes a difference...let me know if posting the whole code would help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: [`var_dump()` is your friend](http://codepad.org/yOOmhaf3)

Comment: Amal, thanks, but var_dump() doesn't print anything if the first two if statements contain no errors.  If either or both of the first two if statements contain an error, var_dump confirms what the error-handling above says.  That being said, the problem I'm having is that if neither of the first two if statements contain an error, it seems the second two if statements are ignored.  I need those to still show an error regardless of the first two if statements.

Comment: using break/continue may serve your purpose !

Comment: Shivanshu, I tried a few things with your suggestion but to no avail, the same problem is happening.

Comment: Why are you trying to force for type check in `if` statements? These are simple BOOL and STRING types. And, are you sure that you have no error with your `$result`? 'Cause mostly database errors will terminate the script from the line which error has occurred. Check for your `$result` to see that it has the right data.

Comment: $result returns correct data from the query, based on the inputs.  The code is not terminating, it's simply ignoring the last two if statements and assuming all is correct and executing the else statement even if there are errors in the last two if statements.  I do not know a better way to check for 4 errors an print all errors at once within one statement, sorry.